# Delete free version plugin will also delete premium plugin

Tags: plugins

I have written 2 plugins, one is the free version and the other one is the premium version.

free version has the unique folder name ie.

```
/my-plugin
/my-plugin/someotherfiles...
/my-plugin.php
```

premium version is like this:

```
/my-plugin-premium
/my-plugin-premium/someotherfiles...
/my-plugin-premium/my-plugin-premium.php
```

basically free and premium are pretty much the same, except the premium version has more files (ie. extend the functionalities of the plugin). Both plugins do not have uninstall.php

I have tested both plugins, free one is deactivated and premium one is activated, but when I try to delete the free one by clicking on "delete" on wordpress->plugins, the premium plugin is also deleted, why is that?

Comment: You will need to ask thee plugin's author

Comment: You would need to share the code in order for others to be able to determine why it is deleting both. Something in the code is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress remembers plugins by folder_name/main_plugin_file_name. So please make sure that both free and premium plugins folder names are not the same. Check it. If the names are different, it should not delete both plugins on deleting one.

If your problem persists even when the folder names are different, then there must be some code which is doing that. In that case, please share your plugins details so we can look into it further!

Thanks!